# BJT saturation question

Tags: mosfet, bjt, saturation

For the following question, how do we find \$I_B\$ and \$I_C\$?

Would it be

$$I_C = \frac{V_{in}-V_{BE}}{80k}$$

and

$$I_B = \frac{12-0.12}{5k}$$

[image]

Comment: You have Ib and Ic the swaped.

Answer (score 1):

You have your IB and IC backwards in your calculations.  Otherwise, you are on the right track.